# How do they accomplish the "zombie walking with a broken ankle" effect?

Tags: effects, make-up, shaun-of-the-dead

Zombies are often shown dragging one foot behind them. The clip below shows an example from *Shaun of the Dead* (2004). You can see the zombie dragging its foot at 2:06.

How is this practical effect accomplished?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve that is to use an amputee.  And yes, zombie-type movies use a **lot** of amputees as extras.  It's just easier and cheaper than green-screening something like that.  Attach a prosthetic, and they can hobble, crawl, get their legs bitten off, whatever you want with a little practical special effects.

If it was a main character played by an actor that you know is not an amputee, then they will use a green sock and create the amputation effect in post processing.